# não consigo acessar o boolean do player , como prossigo?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, javascript-eventos

o codigo

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable,KeyListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int WIDTH = 240;
    public static int HEIGHT = 120;
    public static int SCALE = 3;

    public BufferedImage layer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    public Player player;

    public Game(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        player = new Player(100,HEIGHT-10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(game).start();
    }

    public void tick(){
        player.tick();
    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = layer.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        player.render(g);
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(layer,0,0,WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,null);
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000/60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tick();
            render();       }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){            
         player.right(true);    
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
          player.left(true);
        }
       }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
   }
```

e o codigo do player:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player {

    public boolean right,left;
    public int x,y;

    public Player(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void tick(){
        if(right)
        {
        x++;    
        }
        else if(left){
            x--;
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x,y,40,10);
    }

}
```

os erros:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method right(boolean) is undefined for the type Player
    The method left(boolean) is undefined for the type Player

```
at pong.Game.keyPressed(Game.java:79)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6590)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6409)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1140)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1010)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:836)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

como prossigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o erro seu ocorre na denominação dos valores booleanos. O certo seria:

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){            
     player.right=true;
     player.left=false; 
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
      player.left=true;
      player.right=false;
    }
   }

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    player.left=false;
    player.right=false;
}
```

Fiz umas melhorias, caso goste.

Comment: não funcioneu :(

Comment: Poderia informar o erro? Copiei o seu código e testei aqui no meu e funcionou perfeitamente. Tente somente copiar as minhas duas funções e substituir pelas suas.

Comment: meu amigo sou uma anta obrigado

Comment: Por nada, poderia marcar como resposta correta?